# What is $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1+1/x}{1+1/x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

What is $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1+1/x}{1+1/x^2}$$

I'm thinking is does not exist, but I'm not certain.

I tried to factor out $\frac{1}{x}$ from the fraction but that doesn't help. Then I thought the denominator could be re-written as

$1^2+(\frac{1}{x})^2$ but I'm not sure how to factor it into a form that would cancel anything out.  So since I"m running out of ideas I'm thinking the limit does not exist.

Comment: the limit can also easily be seen by doing power series expansion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply the numerator and denominator by $x^2$. You should get a limit of 0.

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1+1/x}{1+1/x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2+x}{x^2+1}=0$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1+1/x}{1+1/x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1+1/x}{1+1/x^2} \cdot \frac{x^2}{x^2} \\ = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2+x}{x^2+1}\end{align}$$ You can plug in zero directly to evaluate this limit. Alternatively, you can make the substitution $y= \frac{1}{x}$ and take the equivalent limit as $y \to \infty$. It might be easier to see $$\lim_{y\to \infty}\frac{1+y}{1+y^2}=0$$ as the $y^2$ in the denominator will overpower everything in the numerator and drive the fraction to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

for $x$ small, $$\dfrac{1 + \frac 1 x}{1 + \frac 1 {x^2}} = \dfrac{\frac 1 x+1}{\frac 1{x^2}} +\cdots = x^2\left(\frac 1 x + 1\right)+\cdots \to 0 $$

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do in this instance is to simply not consider the limit at first:
$$
\frac{1+\frac{1}{x}}{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}=\frac{x+1}{x}\cdot\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}=\frac{x^2+x}{x^2+1}.
$$
At this point, it becomes clear that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1+\frac{1}{x}}{1+\frac{1}{x^2}} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2+x}{x^2+1}=\frac{\lim_{x\to 0} (x^2+x)}{\lim_{x\to 0}(x^2+1)}=\frac{\lim_{x\to 0}x^2+\lim_{x\to 0}x}{\lim_{x\to 0}x^2+\lim_{x\to 0}1}=\frac{0+0}{0+1}=\frac{0}{1}=0.
$$